Adding Code to Experience Builder Text Widget
I have some Arcade code I wrote (that surprisingly works) and I'd like to insert the code into a Text Widget in Experience Builder (I need to replace the XXX in the image below with the code). The code runs in Map Viewer's PopUp Expressions, but I want to put the code in a Text Widget on the Experience Builder's landing page.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to do this. The only options I get are in the limited Dynamic Content selection (see below) where I cannot actually insert code, I have to use the basic pre-programmed functions.

Is there another way to get my code into the Text Widget? The Text Widget obviously accepts code, but only in basic commands as far as I know.
My code is pretty easy, see below:
// Write a script to return a value to show in the text. 
var count = 0;
var features = FeatureSetByName($map, "HC footprints");
for (var feature in features) {
    if (feature.lifecycle_status == 'Active') {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;



Unfortunately, experience builder does not support Arcade (even though the dialogue boxes would lead you to believe this).
However, this is a work around in the UI!
Where it says "Selected Features" below the "HC footprints" drop down, you are able to make a new view of the data where you can apply a query to select by attribute where lifecycle_status is Active. Once this view is created, make sure you change the dialogue box to display the name of your new view, then you can use the "expression" section of the linked data dialogue to produce the count of features and return that to your text element.
